# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context xCode 14.1

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone tell me, what's wrong in my code or how i can decompose this method to debug, i have latest xCode v.14.1 (14B47b), somehow it compiles on v.13.4.1 -_-

```
extension WebSocket {
    @available(macOS 10.15, *) func connectUntilBody(write: String? = nil ) async throws -> Data? {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in // <-- Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
            var result: Result<Data?, Error> = .success(nil)
            onEvent = { [weak self] event in
                if let body = event.body {
                    result = .success(body)
                    let group = DispatchGroup()
                    if let write = write {
                        group.enter()
                        self?.write(string: write) {
                            group.leave()
                        }
                    }
                    group.notify(queue: .main) {
                        self?.disconnect()
                    }
                } else if case let .error(error) = event {
                    error.flatMap { result = .failure($0) }
                    self?.disconnect()
                } else if case .cancelled = event {
                    continuation.resume(with: result)
                }
            }
            connect()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some major issues:

1. If you mark the function as `throws` you have to `resume` the error.
2. You **must** `resume` the data in the *happy path*.
3. The `DispatchGroup` makes no sense. As the `continuation` is `async` anyway you can `resume` in the `write` closure.
4. You must also ensure that `resume` is called **only once**.

To answer the question:

If the compiler cannot infer the type of the `continuation` you have to annotate it. In your case

```
(continuation: Result<Data?,Error>)in
```

But you can also call `continuation.resume(returning:)` to return the data, and `continuation.resume(throwing:)` to return the error. See issue 1).

You should also return non-optional `Data` otherwise an error. By the way that's the goal of the `Result` type.

Comment: The type is probably `continuation: CheckedContinuation<Data?, Error>`, there's a [`resume(with result: Result<T, E>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation/resume(with:)-3gh60).